# usecols keyword argument of pd.read_csv says it expects list[str] but the documentation says otherwise

Tags: python, pandas

I'm using PyCharm 2022.3.3 (Professional Edition) and I have the following warning:
[image]

MRE:

```py
import pandas as pd; path_to_csv = "mycsv.csv"; df_db = pd.read_csv(path_to_csv, usecols=[0])
```

The documentation (https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html) says:

> usecols list-like or callable, optional Return a subset of the
> columns. If list-like, **all elements must either be positional (i.e.
> integer indices into the document columns) or strings that correspond
> to column names provided either by the user in names or inferred from
> the document header row(s)**. If names are given, the document header
> row(s) are not taken into account. For example, a valid list-like
> usecols parameter would be [0, 1, 2] or ['foo', 'bar', 'baz']. Element
> order is ignored, so usecols=[0, 1] is the same as [1, 0]. To
> instantiate a DataFrame from data with element order preserved use
> pd.read_csv(data, usecols=['foo', 'bar'])[['foo', 'bar']] for columns
> in ['foo', 'bar'] order or pd.read_csv(data, usecols=['foo',
> 'bar'])[['bar', 'foo']] for ['bar', 'foo'] order.
>
> If callable, the callable function will be evaluated against the
> column names, returning names where the callable function evaluates to
> True. An example of a valid callable argument would be lambda x:
> x.upper() in ['AAA', 'BBB', 'DDD']. Using this parameter results in
> much faster parsing time and lower memory usage.

I'm lost as to what is happening.

I’m using pandas 1.5.3 and python 3.11.1.

Comment: Please update your question with the pandas version too

Comment: Done, sorry I had forgotten

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was a problem with `pandas-stubs`. An issue has been made and a PR just got merged.

Comment: It's better to link the PR in your answer.